# Enable Mac Application To Wake Display

Tags: macos

I have an app that generates keystrokes.  If the screen saver is running, the keystrokes will bring the display to normal operating mode, and the app works correctly.  However, if the display is in sleep mode, the keystrokes don't wake the display, and the app doesn't function correctly.  Is there anything that I can do to cause the app to wake the display?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this works.  [Technical Q&A QA1340](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1340/_index.html) discusses the API for preventing the display from going to sleep.  It's possible that asserting that the display shouldn't sleep will wake a display that is asleep.

Answer (score 0):

If your demand is to prevent sleep, you could use UpdateSystemActivity(). Check [Technical Q&A QA1160](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1160/_index.html).